# expanding a callback function?

Tags: c#, lambda, keyboard-hook

Reading through George Mamaladze c# "global mouse key hook" source code I am trying to figure how some code works. Here is the "corazon" generally

```
public delegate IntPtr HookProcedure(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private static Handle HookGlobal(int hookId, Callback callback)
{
    HookProcedure hookProc = (code, param, lParam) => MyProc(code, param, lParam, callback);

    Handle handle = SetWindowsHookEx(
            hookId,
            hookProc,
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.BaseAddress,
            0);
    return handle;
}

private static IntPtr MyProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Callback callback)
{            
    var callbackData = new CallbackData(wParam, lParam);
    bool continueProcessing = callback(callbackData);
    if (!continueProcessing) 
    { return new IntPtr(-1); }
    return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The message pump set by WinApi function SetWindowsHookEx will call the MyProc method with message data.

```
HHOOK WINAPI SetWindowsHookEx(
  _In_ int       idHook,
  _In_ HOOKPROC  lpfn,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hMod,
  _In_ DWORD     dwThreadId
);
```

> According to MSDN, the HOOKPROC type defines a pointer to the callback function. (example...) MouseProc is a placeholder for the application-defined or library-defined function name. (There are several placeholder procedure callbacks...)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(
    _In_ int    code,
         WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
);
```

Does the hookProc delegate instance keep reference to the lambda and thus to MyProc method in George's code?
Here is a simpler approach from Stephen Taub's MSDN blog

```
private delegate IntPtr HookProcedure(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
private static HookProcedure procedure = Callback;
private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;        

public static void SetHook()
{
    _hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
        procedure,
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule,
        0);        
}

private static IntPtr Callback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

They should achieve the same thing. What's George up to with this warped stuff? An explanation may help with my dizziness or shortness of breath.

Comment: The solution by George Mamaladze does not look reliable, how is he ensuring `hookProc` doesn't get GC'ed? For that reason alone I'd trust Stephen Toub's code more.

Comment: @Lukazoid now i did say "generally " concerning the code** but a quick glance at mamaladze code doesn't reveal that sort of mechanism, it's this use of lambda i don't know

Comment: This is a reasonable question with a very poor title, I suggest you edit that

Comment: I see a memory bleed. Anyone else see it?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the hookProc delegate instance keep reference to the lambda and thus to MyProc method in George's code?

No it does not, `hookProc` may be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the function exits and your hook will no longer function, you need to keep a reference to the delegate like in Stepen's code to stop it from happening.

Comment: Wouldn't a static callback do the same thing?

Comment: i am using succinct code like stephen's but i would like to expose an external callback within the hook callback function parameters too like george

Comment: @code4life no actually, I have run into it myself. If you did `SetWindowsHookEx(hookId, MyProc, ...` that actually gets compiled to `SetWindowsHookEx(hookId, new HookProcedure(MyProc), ...` and that hidden delegate can be garbage collected once SetWindowsHookEx returns. If SetWindowsHookEx then tries to use the callback you will get a `CallbackOnCollectedDelegate` error. See [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878729/thread-hook-procedure-is-no-longer-called-after-pressing-tab-several-times-why/19626866#19626866) on this same API call for more details.

Comment: @JediCommymullah What you could do is have a `static Dictionary<Callback, HookProcedure>` that you hold the callbacks in. When a user wants to unsubscribe you can just remove the callback from the dictionary.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: ah, thanks for the info, makes sense!

Comment: that's soooooo interesting scott. a dictionary would really open it up. maybe i could stash hookProc in a field and pass that instead?

Comment: @JediCommymullah One thing to be careful of, Dictionary is not thread safe, either use `ConcurrentDictionary` or put a lock around it.